# C# ComboBox.Items is a property or is a array?

Tags: c#, combobox

Reference to Microsoft Developer Network, 
ComboBox.Items Property syntax is

```
public ComboBox.ObjectCollection Items { get; }
```

It show me that `ComboBox.Items` will return an object. And that I can use this object add/remove... method to maintain combobox content

But why I can use `ComboBox.Items[index]` array to return value to me
for example, `ComboBox.Items[0].Text`

So, I don't understand **items** is a property or is a array.

Comment: A property has nothing to do with the type. A property is simply a field with getters and/or setters. Further, in C#, an indexer does *not* mean a type is an array. So to answer your question - `Items` is a property and a collection type.

Comment: Maybe a simple question but it is not duplicate of linked question.

Answer (score 4):

`ComboBox.ObjectCollection` is property which has a return type that supports indexing and is collection.

This type implements all these interfaces, which makes it a collection and allows you to do indexing on it.

```
Public Class ObjectCollection
    Implements IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

MSDN Link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's a property of type `ObjectCollection`.

`ObjectCollection` implements the interfaces `IList`, `ICollection`, and `IEnumerable`.  Items in such a collection can be accessed in a manner that appears similar to accessing items in an array.